# Check if dictionary contains a certain string from command output

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, string-comparison, pexpect

I'm new to learning python and pexpect and I'm trying to check if a dictionary contains a certain string from some command output but I'm having trouble.

So say I send some command called "list" to my terminal, it outputs details of a certain product:

```
->list
Color: Maroon Red
Height: 150cm
Code: 4KG-LV
Material: Aluminum
Brand: Toyota 
#and hundreds of more lines...
```

I have a variable that represents a dictionary that outputs this when I print it using 'print(license_type)':

```
{'license': '4kg-lv'}
```

I basically want to check if the code '4KG-LV' from the output of the list command is equal to the value '4kg-lv' from the license in the dictionary.

Doing this:

```
exp.sendline("list")
exp.expect('(?<=Code:\s).*(?=[\r\n])')
firstString = exp.after
print(firstString)
```

parses the output of the list command using regex and gets/prints the value 4KG-LV. I can confirm this works.

If I were to put all of this in a python script and check if the two values are equal (ignoring capitalization), it should pass the check. However, when I try to check if the first string (the code from the list command) is in the dictionary, it outputs 'NOT EQUAL'

```
exp.sendline("list")
exp.expect('(?<=Code:\s).*(?=[\r\n])')
firstString = exp.after

# convert dictionary to string
secondString = str(license_type)

if firstString.lower() in secondString.lower()
    print("EQUAL")
else:
    print("NOT EQUAL")
```

I'm not allowed to change the key names/capitalization of what's in the dictionary. I tried converting the dictionary to a string and also used .lower() to convert both strings to lowercase. I'm not sure what I did wrong and would appreciate any help or references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting the dictionary to a string just access the value of the key `license` and convert it to a lowercase string and check if the `firstString` and it are equal. I am assuming that the regex you are using is correct.

```
license_type = {'license': '4kg-lv'}
exp.sendline("list")
exp.expect('(?<=Code:\s).*(?=[\r\n])')
firstString = exp.after

if firstString.lower() == license_type.get("license").lower():
    print("EQUAL")
else:
    print("NOT EQUAL")
```

I tested it out in my iPython shell so it should work:

```
In [3]: "4KG-LV".lower() == license_type.get("license").lower()
Out[3]: True
```

Comment: It's still printing 'NOT EQUAL' for some reason. Do you know why this might be? I printed the firstString.lower() and got '4kg-lv' and then printed license_type.get("license").lower() and also got '4kg-lv'. I have no idea why it's still not passing the test

Comment: @william its working on my end are you sure you are using `==` and not `is`? If you are using `is` to check equality it will return `NOT EQUAL`.

Comment: @william is it working now? It could be an issue with the regex then.

Comment: It works now - thank you! It was my regex part - I think it was adding an extra space to the string